# Table is not emptied when the radio button is selected

Tags: javascript

I try to empty table when I manually select 'Online' radio button mode but I'm still getting the data in the table

[image: online offline radiobutton]

To implement this change I'm trying with javascript, but without success

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var isRequestInProgress = false;
    var mode = document.querySelector('input[name="mode"]:checked').value;
    var table = $('#resultsTable').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: function(d) {
                d.mode = document.querySelector('input[name="mode"]:checked').value;
                d.start_date = document.getElementById('start_date').value || '1900-01-01';
                d.end_date = document.getElementById('end_date').value || '2100-12-31';
                d.limit = document.getElementById('limit').value || 100;  // Default value
                d.search_term = document.getElementById('search_term').value;
                d.case_insensitive = document.getElementById('case_insensitive').checked ? 'on' : 'off';
                d.topic = document.querySelector('input[name="topic"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name="topic"]:checked').value : '666';  // Default value
                d.start = d.start || 0;  // Add the offset
                d.length = d.length || 10;  // Add the limit
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: null, defaultContent: '<input type="checkbox" class="select-row">' },
            { data: 'file_name' },
            { data: 'message_link', render: function(data, type, row) {
                return '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }},
            { data: null, defaultContent: '<button class="download-btn">Scarica</button>' }
        ],
        drawCallback: function() {
            $('.download-btn').on('click', function() {
                var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            });

            $('.select-row').on('click', function() {
                $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('selected');
            });
        }
    });

    table.on('init.dt', function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name="mode"]').forEach(function(radioButton) {
            radioButton.addEventListener('change', function() {
                mode = this.value;
                if (mode === 'online') {
                    table.clear().draw();  // Clear the table when switching to "online" mode
                } else {
                    table.ajax.reload();  // Reload data from source when switching to "offline" mode
                }
            });
        });
    });

    var submitButton = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (isRequestInProgress) {
            return;
        }

        // Updates the value of "mode" to reflect the current value of the radio button
        mode = document.querySelector('input[name="mode"]:checked').value;

        if (mode === 'online') {
            sendRequest();
        }
    });

    function sendRequest() {
        var mode = document.querySelector('input[name="mode"]:checked').value;
        var start_date = document.getElementById('start_date').value || '1900-01-01';
        var end_date = document.getElementById('end_date').value || '2100-12-31';
        var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value || 100;  // Default value
        var search_term = document.getElementById('search_term').value;
        var case_insensitive = document.getElementById('case_insensitive').checked ? 'on' : 'off';
        var topic = document.querySelector('input[name="topic"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name="topic"]:checked').value : '666';  // Default value

        submitButton.value = "Ricerca in corso...";
        isRequestInProgress = true;

        fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                'mode': mode,
                'start_date': start_date,
                'end_date': end_date,
                'limit': limit,
                'search_term': search_term,
                'case_insensitive': case_insensitive,
                'topic': topic
            })
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();  // Assume that the server returns JSON
        }).then(function(data) {
            // Clear the table and add the new data
            table.clear();
            table.rows.add(data).draw();
        }).finally(function() {
            if (mode === 'online') {
                submitButton.disabled = false;
            }
            submitButton.value = "Submit";
            isRequestInProgress = false;
        });
    }
});
```

There are 2 relevant parts

**Assigning the change event to the radio buttons**:

```
table.on('init.dt', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="mode"]').forEach(function(radioButton) {
        radioButton.addEventListener('change', function() {
            mode = this.value;
            if (mode === 'online') {
                table.clear().draw();  // Clear the table when switching to "online" mode
            } else {
                table.ajax.reload();  // Reload data from source when switching to "offline" mode
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In this code block, I'm assigning a change event handler to each radio button. When the user selects a radio button, the event handler is triggered. If the user selected "online", the table is emptied. If the user selected "offline", the data is reloaded from the AJAX source.

**Emptying the table and adding new data in the `sendRequest()` method:**

```
fetch('/', {
    // ...
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();  // Assume that the server returns JSON
}).then(function(data) {
    // Clear the table and add the new data
    table.clear();
    table.rows.add(data).draw();
}).finally(function() {
    // ...
});
```

In this part you are sending a request to the server and getting a response. I assume the response is in JSON format. When the answer is received, then empty the table
This is in theory, but in practice the table is not emptied

Comment: Are you sure toggling the radio buttons triggers a new HTTP request every time you click? it seems it only fetches the data the first time you load the page. Use Chrome Dev Tools > Network tab

Comment: @Normal I think so, you can check [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/BBHmwLa.gif)

Comment: Are you using and JavaScript libraries, like DataTables for jQuery? Add the proper tags to your question, so people that know about DataTables will see the question.